# Why can I get Kripke's semantic tableaux to prove that $C \land x = x$ semantically entails $x = x \land{} \neg{}C$

Tags: logic

[Kripke 1959](http://www.naturalthinker.net/trl/texts/Kripke,Saul/Kripke%20S.%20-%20A%20Completeness%20Theorem%20in%20Modal%20Logic.pdf) uses semantic tableaux containing a conjunction of formulae $A_1 \land A_2 \land ... \land A_n$ in the left column and a formula $B$ in the right column to prove semantic entailment. As far as I can tell, a tableau with $C \land x = x$ on the left side and $x = x \land{} \neg{}C$ on the right side is well-formed: None of the construction rules force us to do anything about $C$ or $x=x$, they only require that we have $C$ on the left side if $\neg C$ appears in the right side.

The tableau is also closed, since by definition any tableau is closed if "$a = a$, for some variable $a$, occurs in its right column".

This should mean that there exists no model in which $C \land x = x$ is valid and $x = x \land \neg C$ is invalid, which is absurd, since in any model in which $C \land x = x$ is valid, $x = x \land \neg C$ should be invalid.

So where did I go wrong? Is $x = x \land \neg C$ not a suitable formula to put in as $B$ in the semantic tableau, or does $x = x$ not "occur" in the right column in the relevant sense since it is a subformula?

**Edit**: In Kripke 1959, if the tableau is closed, the formula on the right side is semantically entailed by the formula on the left side:

"Theorem 1. $B$ is semantically entailed by $A_1, A_2, ..., A_n$ if and only if the construction beginning with $A_1, ..., A_n$ in a left column and $B$ in a right column is closed."

**Another edit**: The relevant point seems to be the end of Kripke's proof of Lemma 1 where he claims that a closed construction where $B$ is not semantically entailed by $A_1, ..., A_n$ would require (in the relevant case) for some member of **K** (the set of possible assignments) to assign **F** to $a=a$. This seems to imply that only constructions count as closed where the right side exclusively contains $a=a$, since from $\neg (X\land a=a)$ it doesn't follow that $\neg (a=a)$ (or that $a=a$ is assigned **F**).

Comment: Not clear... $C$ does **not** entail $x=x \land \lnot C$. Try with a truth assignment $v$ such that $v(C)=$ **t**.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Of course $C$ does not entail $x = x \land \neg C$, it can't, and that's what I'm saying. I'm wondering what subtlety I'm missing that prevents me from using Kripke's Theorem 1 to (wrongly) show that it does entail it, other than just saying that Kripke's Theorem is wrong.

Comment: It seems that you are changing your question as long as you are reading the paper... It seems to me that you are missing a pre-requisite for Kripke's paper: the konwledge of the method of [Semantic tableaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA My first edit was to show that Kripke uses closedness to show semantic entailment, not its absence. I knew that he did, hence my question, but it appeared to me that some people might not know it. My second edit is there to lead the reader to the point where things look strange to me in Kripke's proof, because I hope that it is illuminating ofr anyone who wants to answer my question. My third edit, where I changed the formula, was because - as you said in your answer - I had missed one of the construction rules and Contd.

Comment: the construction in my original question was not well-formed. My question, why any construction containing $x = x$ on the right side is valid, when I can think of counterexamples, has not changed, even though my counterexample has changed. I was not aware how Semantic tableaux in general work, and therefore not of the fact that Kripke's usage is different, but it doesn't really matter - what matters is how Kripke's semantic tableaux work, where closedness of the construction means semantic entailment of the right side by the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Tableaux method used by Kripke, must be interpreted as follows: right column is *false*, left column is *true*.

Consider the rule $\land$l: if $A \land B$ appears in the *left* column, put both $A$ and $B$ in the *left* column.

This is consistent with the fact that the only way to evaluate $A \land B$ to *true* is to have both $A$ and $B$ true.

According to this interpretation, we can imagine "derived" rules:

> $\to$r : if we have $A \to B$ in the *right* column, then put $A$ in the *left* and $B$ in the *right*.

This is so because $A \to B$ is *false* only when $A$ is *true* and $B$ is *false*.

---

How the Tableaux method is used to prove *validity* ?

The method works by contradiction.

Example: we start with $A \land \lnot A$ on the left (i.e. assume it *true*) and we immediately get $A$ and $\lnot A$ in the left column. We have a contradcition and thus the (only path of the) tableaux closes.

This means that the original formula is *unsatisfiable*, i.e. that its negation: $A \lor \lnot A$, is a *tautology*.

In order to prove *entailment*: $A \to B$ we work again by contradiciton: assume the contrary, i.e. $A \land \lnot B$ on the left (i.e. assume it true).

If the tableaux closes, we have that the formula is *unsatisfiable*, i.e. its negation is *valid*.

But $\lnot (A \land \lnot B)$ is equivalent to $A \to B$.

And $A \to B$ is a tautology iff $A \vDash B$.

---

The rule for $\land$ (see page 4) is:

> $\land$r : if $A \land B$ appears in the right column there are two alternatives: either put $A$ in the right column or put $B$ in the right column.

Again, this is consistent with the interpretation taht $A \land B$ is *false* when either $A$ is false or $B$ is false.

How apply it to $C \land x=x$ on the left and $x=x \land \lnot C$ on the right ?

Clearly, the left does not entail the right, and thus we do not expect that the tableaux will close.

We first unpack $C \land x=x$ with $\land$l, and we get both $C$ and $x=x$ on the left.

Then we apply $\land$r and we have to branches: the first alternative, with $x=x$ on the right and the second with $\lnot C$ on the right.

The first alternative, with $x=x$ on the right, will close. This is consistent with the interpretation above: right is *false* and no interpretation can falsify $x=x$.

But in the second alternative we have $C$ and $x=x$ on the left and $\lnot C$ on the right, and the branch will not close: there is no contradicition: $C$ on the left is *true* and $\lnot C$ on the right is *false*, i.e. again $C$ is *true*.

In this case the tableaux is not closed and thus we cannot apply Lemma 1 to prove entailment.

And the result is correct, because:

> $(C \land x=x) \nvDash (x=x \land \lnot C)$.

The result gives us also a valuation $v$ fasifying the purported entailment: with $v(C)=$ **t**, and obviously $v(x=x)=$ **t**, we have satisfied the left formula but not the right one.

Thus, the right is **not** entailed by the left.

Please, note that: a tableaux is closed when all its paths are closed. See page 5:

> Because of $\land$r, a construction [...] may split into alternative sets; in this case we say that the construction is closed iff **all** its alterntive sets are closed.

---

*Regarding last edit*

How we have to read Lemma 1 ?

If $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are on the left and $B$ on the right closes, then $A_1, \ldots A_n \vDash B$.

Correct; if the assumption that $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are all *true* and $B$ is *false* is contradictory, then the set $\{ A_1, \ldots, A_n, \lnot B \}$ is *unsatisfiable*, that means:

> $A_1, \ldots, A_n \vDash B$.

Comment: Now I think I understand: I have to apply all construction rules before checking whether the right side contains $a=a$, and in applying rule $\Lambda r$, I end up with two alternative tableaux, both of which need to be closed in order for the construction need to be closed, and one of those will not contain $a=a$ in the right side. Sorry for taking so long to understand what you were saying.

Comment: @sgf - Correct; but the condition for closure is: to find a *contradiciton* (i.e. an unsatisfiable case). Not only $a=a$ on the right (false) is unsatisfiable (and thus the closure) but also a for mula $C$ boh on the right (false) and on the left (true) or, which is the same: $C$ and $\lnot C$ on the same side, that means both true or both false.